# Google Adwords Conversion Tracking After Event No New Page

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

It seems like a pretty common question but I haven't found a solution that fits my needs.

I need to send out successful conversion tracking code back to google upon a successful action/event.

My workflow process is such..

A user gets to a `register` page with a form...

When the form submits and the user is successfully registered, they are redirected to a `dashboard` page.

How can I fire off the conversion form this event/goal after my API says it was a success?

Similarly, when a user makes a purchase its the same workflow.

`checkout` -> `dashboard`

*Side note about purchases: I would like to have a variable conversion value for each purchase (I can send amounts out from my server)*

How can I make sure that:

1. Every time a user visits their `dashboard` a tracking code does not get fired out?
2. The proper tracking code conversion is sent (register or purchase)
3. The code is only sent upon a successful action (not on button click but on a  successful return from my server)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the key is NOT to fire pixel at dashboard onload(), but fire it only after API confirm the success - for example with [JavaScript promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

Alternative to this can be using Google Tag Manager, which should be able to [fire pixel only after certain rules are accomplished](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en)